# Dedekind ring in the complete discrete valued field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $ K $ be a complete discrete valued field and $ A \neq K $ be a subring of $ K $. When $ A $ is a Dedekind ring, is $ A $ a DVR?

For the integral domain $ R $, the following are equivalent:

(1) $ R $ is a Dedekind ring.

(2) $ R $ is a field or a one-dimensional noetherian normal ring.
(Here, the ring in which the localization by each prime ideal becomes the integral domain is called the normal ring.)

Therefore, $ A $ in my question is a one-dimensional noetherian normal ring.

For the ring $ R $, the following are equivalent:

(1) $ R $ is a DVR.

(2) $ R $ is a one-dimensional noetherian normal ring and a local ring.

From the above, I would like to show that $ A $ in my question is a local ring.

Comment: Not necessarily: a counter-example is $\mathbf Z$, which is contained in $\mathbf Q_p$: it is a P.I.D., hence a Dedekind ring, and is not  a local ring, but its closure for the $p$-adic topology is the  local ring of $p$-adic integers..

Comment: Remark: specifying that $A\neq K$ does not guarantee that $A$ is not a field: consider $k\subseteq k((t)).$

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. I didn't notice a simple example.

Comment: @Stahl As you pointed out, "$ A $ is not a field" is the correct.